# how to remove the text and print the lines from removed text line in a file in java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a file abc.txt that has lines as

### abc.txt

```
Ethernet 1/1 

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3

abs_mod_

jjj

kkkk

ll

abs_mod_

interface 6

interface 7
```

I have deleted the lines in between abs_mod_ and also lines starting with abs_mod_

but final output I am getting is double spaces between interface 3 and 6.

### abc.txt

```
Ethernet 1/1 

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3


interface 6

interface 7
```

To avoid I have written code like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("abc.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        boolean flag = true;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("abs_mod_")){
                if(flag)    flag = false;
                else        flag = true;
            }else if(flag){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString().replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I except the code should not be hardcode the spaces like this
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString().replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n"));

to get output as

### abc.txt

```
Ethernet 1/1 

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3

interface 6

interface 7
```

Is any other way to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your end goal, you could just use regular expressions to replace the pattern (between your match strings) with an empty string.

See the following example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("abc.txt");
            String fileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

            // Remove all text between 'abs_mod_' also removing any preceding\training line breaks (if any)
            String fileContentsCleaned = fileContents .replaceAll("(?s)\n?abs_mod_\n.*\nabs_mod_\n?", "");

            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(fileContentsCleaned);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```